# console.writeline >> redirectedoutput.txt garbled

Tags: .net, console-application

I have a VB.NET 3.5 sp1 console application running on Windows XP sp3 from a batch file:

```
"D:\Program Files\PartsDepotJob\PartsDepotJob.exe" >> "D:\Program Files\PartsDepotJob\partdepot.log.txt"
```

The output looks like the following:

> 2/10/2009 9:03:19 AM
>       Processing PO#:     2100 in 002
>       Created OE#     135
>       Processing PO#:     2100 in 003
>       Created OE#     136
>       DONE
>       2/10/2009 9:03:30 AM
>       Processing PO#:     2100 in 002
>       Created OE#     137
>       Processing PO#:     2100 in 003
>       Created OE#     138
>       DONE

However when I run the same thing at my client on their Windows 2003 sp2 (also w/ .NET 3.5 sp1) box the output gets garbled as follows:

> 2/9/2009 4:03:37 PM
>       DONE
>       2/9/2009 4:04:06 PM
>       DONE
>       2/9/2009 4:11:01 PM
>       DONE
>       2/9/2009 4:30:23 PM
>       Processing PO#:  1649400 in 702
>       Created OE#
>       1/1/1900 4:30:26 PMCreated OE#      49
>       1/1/1900 4:30:26 PMProcessing PO#:  1649500 in 702
>       Created OE#      49
>       1/1/1900 4:30:28 PMCreated OE#      50
>       1/1/1900 4:30:28 PMDONE

ie., sometimes CrLf are removed and the output sometimes seems to be prefixed with  1/1/1900 {time}.

Any idea's as to what could cause this?

The relevent code is a follows:

```
Imports Wisys.AllSystem
Imports Wisys.Oe
Imports Wisys.Po
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Linq

Public Class clsPartsDepot
    Private wsConn As Wisys.AllSystem.ConnectionInfo = Nothing
    Private wsPartDepotSalesOrd As Wisys.Oe.OrderEntryTables = Nothing

    Public Function ProcessPartDepotOrders() As Boolean
        Dim errMsg As String = ""
        Try
            Console.WriteLine(Now().ToString)
            ''//sendBadPOLineEmailtoDepot("test")
            Dim dsPO As New Data.DataSet
            Dim dbName As String = ""
            Dim dbServer As String
            Dim partDepotDbName As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("partDepotDbName")
            Dim partDepotDbServer As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("partdepotDBserver")
            Dim KeyName As String = ""
            Dim billToCompany As String ''//, billtoCompAddr1 As String
            Dim dtBillTo As DataTable
            Dim i As Integer = 1


            Dim appkeyQry = From key In ConfigurationManager.AppSettings Where key Like "CompanyDbName*" Select key

            ''//for each company database look for PO's
            For Each KeyName In appkeyQry
                dbName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(KeyName)
                dbServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CompanyDbServer" & i)
                billToCompany = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(dbName)

                dtBillTo = GetCustomer(billToCompany, partDepotDbName, partDepotDbServer)
                If dtBillTo.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                    Throw New Exception("Customer record for company database '" & dbName & "' not found in the parts depot!")
                End If
                ''//billtoCompAddr1 = dtBillTo.Rows(0)("cmp_fadd1")

                ''//get all the unprocessed, printed PO's from the current company.
                dsPO = GetPoDataset(dbName, dbServer)

                If IsNothing(dsPO) Then
                    Console.WriteLine("Error processing part depot: " & errMsg)
                    Exit Function
                End If

                Dim itemNum As String, qtyOrd As Double, requestDate As Date, promiseDate As Date, lineNum As String, itemPrice As Double
                Dim errNum As Integer = 0
                Dim poNum As String = ""
                ''//for each unprocessed, printed PO in the current company
                For Each dr As DataRow In dsPO.Tables(0).Rows

                    If poNum <> dr("ord_no") Then
                        Console.WriteLine("Processing PO#: " & dr("ord_no") & " in " & dbName)

                        If Not poNum = "" Then 'for first run don't close it, not open
                            wsConn.CloseWisysConnection(TrxEnums.TransactionAction.Commit, errMsg)
                            wsConn.Dispose()
                            wsConn = Nothing
                        End If
                        wsConn = New Wisys.AllSystem.ConnectionInfo
                        OpenWiSysConn(partDepotDbName, partDepotDbServer, True)

                        If Not poNum = "" Then 'for first run don't Dispose it; already equal to nothing
                            If Not IsNothing(wsPartDepotSalesOrd) Then wsPartDepotSalesOrd.Dispose()
                            wsPartDepotSalesOrd = Nothing
                        End If
                        wsPartDepotSalesOrd = New Wisys.Oe.OrderEntryTables
                        wsPartDepotSalesOrd.Connection(wsConn, errMsg)

                        With wsPartDepotSalesOrd.OrderHeader
                            .UserName = My.User.Name
                            .Ship_to_name = If(IsDBNull(dr("cmp_name")), "", dr("cmp_name"))
                            .Ship_to_addr_1 = If(IsDBNull(dr("cmp_fadd1")), "", dr("cmp_fadd1"))
                            .Ship_to_addr_2 = If(IsDBNull(dr("cmp_fadd2")), "", dr("cmp_fadd2"))
                            .Ship_to_addr_3 = If(IsDBNull(dr("cmp_fadd3")), "", dr("cmp_fadd3"))
                            .Ship_to_addr_4 = If(IsDBNull(dr("cmp_fcity")), "", dr("cmp_fcity")) & " , " & _
                            If(IsDBNull(dr("StateCode")), "", dr("StateCode"))
                            .Ship_to_country = If(IsDBNull(dr("cmp_fcounty")), "", dr("cmp_fcounty"))
                            .Oe_po_no = dr("ord_no")
                        End With

                        ''//wsPartDepotSalesOrd.OrderHeader.Status 'readonly
                        errNum = wsPartDepotSalesOrd.OrderHeader.Insert(TrxEnums.OeOrderTypeEnum.Order, "", billToCompany, "", dr("ord_dt"), errMsg)
                        If errNum <> 0 Then
                            Console.WriteLine("Error Creating OE header:" & errMsg)
                        Else
                            Console.WriteLine("Created OE#" & wsPartDepotSalesOrd.OrderHeader.Ord_no)
                        End If
                    End If
                    poNum = dr("ord_no")

                    ''//if error then skip to the next loop iteration until the next PO # and it gets inserted ok
                    If errNum <> 0 Then
                        Continue For
                    End If

                    lineNum = If(IsDBNull(dr("line_no")), Now(), dr("line_no"))
                    itemNum = dr("item_no").ToString
                    qtyOrd = If(IsDBNull(dr("qty_ordered")), 0, CDbl(dr("qty_ordered")))
                    requestDate = If(IsDBNull(dr("request_dt")), Now(), dr("request_dt"))
                    promiseDate = If(IsDBNull(dr("promise_dt")), Now(), dr("promise_dt"))
                    itemPrice = If(IsDBNull(dr("price")), 0, dr("price"))

                    If itemNum.Length > 0 And qtyOrd <> 0 Then
                        CreateLine(wsPartDepotSalesOrd, itemNum, qtyOrd, 0, requestDate, requestDate, promiseDate, itemPrice, poNum)
                        ''//mark as processed, even if above fails. any lines that fail will be added to SO in parts depot by hand.
                        markPoLineAsProcessed(dbName, dbServer, poNum, lineNum)
                    End If

                Next
                poNum = ""
                i = +1
                If Not IsNothing(wsConn) Then
                    wsConn.CloseWisysConnection(TrxEnums.TransactionAction.Commit, errMsg)
                    wsConn.Dispose()
                End If
                If Not IsNothing(wsPartDepotSalesOrd) Then wsPartDepotSalesOrd.Dispose()
                wsConn = Nothing
                wsPartDepotSalesOrd = Nothing
            Next
            Console.WriteLine("DONE")

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Exception processing part depot: " & ex.Message)

        Finally
            Try
                ''//cleanup 
                If Not IsNothing(wsPartDepotSalesOrd) Then
                    wsPartDepotSalesOrd.Dispose()
                    wsPartDepotSalesOrd = Nothing
                End If

                If Not IsNothing(wsConn) Then
                    wsConn.CloseWisysConnection(TrxEnums.TransactionAction.Commit, errMsg)
                    wsConn.Dispose()
                    wsConn = Nothing
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine("Exception exiting part depot: " & ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Try
    End Function

    Private Function GetCustomer(ByVal CustomerNum As String, ByVal db As String, ByVal server As String) As DataTable
        Dim cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Try
            cn.ConnectionString = "Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=" & db & ";server=" & server
            cn.Open()
            cmd = cn.CreateCommand
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@cusnum", CustomerNum))
            cmd.CommandText = "select cmp_name,cmp_fadd1,coalesce(debnr,crdnr) as CusNum from dbo.cicmpy where ltrim(debnr) = @cusnum or ltrim(crdnr) = @cusnum"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(ds)
            If ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                Return ds.Tables(0)
            End If
            Return Nothing
        Finally
            If Not IsNothing(cmd) Then cmd.Dispose()
            If Not IsNothing(cn) Then cn.Dispose()
            If Not IsNothing(da) Then da.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Function

    Private Function GetPoDataset(ByVal db As String, ByVal server As String) As DataSet
        Dim cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dsa As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Try
            Static Dim SQL As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("getPoforPartsDepotSQL")
            cn.ConnectionString = "Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=" & db & ";server=" & server
            cn.Open()
            cmd.Connection = cn
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = SQL
            dsa.SelectCommand = cmd
            dsa.Fill(ds)
            Return ds
        Catch
            Throw
        Finally
            If Not IsNothing(ds) Then ds.Dispose()
            If Not IsNothing(cmd) Then cmd.Dispose()
            If Not IsNothing(cn) Then cn.Close()
            If Not IsNothing(cn) Then cn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Function

    Private Function OpenWiSysConn(ByVal dbName As String, ByVal dbServer As String, ByVal useTran As Boolean) As Boolean
        Try
            Dim errMsg As String = ""

            wsConn.Parameters(dbServer, dbName, "MacMSS")

            If wsConn.OpenWisysConnection(useTran, errMsg) <> 0 Then
                Console.WriteLine("Error processing part depot: " & errMsg)
                Return False
            End If

            Return True
        Catch
            Throw
        End Try
    End Function

    Private Function CreateLine(ByVal p_oOEObj As Wisys.Oe.OrderEntryTables, ByVal partNum As String, ByVal qtyOrdered As Double, ByVal qtyToShip As Double, ByVal RequestDate As Date, ByVal RequestShipDate As Date, ByVal PromiseDate As Date, ByVal price As Double, ByVal PONum As String) As Boolean
        Dim OeLine As OEORDLIN
        Dim p_sRtnErrMsg As String = ""
        Dim p_lRtnVal As Long
        Dim p_lRtnLineNumber As Long

        With p_oOEObj
            ''//p_lRtnVal = .OrderHeader.Read(TrxEnums.OeOrderTypeEnum.Order, p_sRtnOrder, True, True, True, p_bRtnRecFound, p_sRtnErrMsg)

            OeLine = .OrderHeader.OrderLines.Add(TrxEnums.OrderLineType.InventoryItem, partNum.ToUpper, "", qtyOrdered, qtyToShip, price, price, RequestDate, PromiseDate, RequestShipDate, True, p_sRtnErrMsg)

            p_lRtnVal = OeLine.Insert(p_lRtnLineNumber, p_sRtnErrMsg)


            If p_lRtnVal = 0 Then
                Return True
            End If

            Console.WriteLine("Error creating sales order line# " & p_lRtnLineNumber & ": " & p_sRtnErrMsg)
            sendBadPOLineEmailtoDepot("Error creating sales order line for PO# " & PONum & " becuase of an error: " & p_sRtnErrMsg)
            Return False

        End With
    End Function

    Private Function markPoLineAsProcessed(ByVal DB As String, ByVal server As String, ByVal poOrdNum As String, ByVal poLineNum As String) As Boolean
        Dim cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Try
            Static Dim SQL As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("markPoLineAsSendToDepotSQL")

            cn.ConnectionString = "Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=" & DB & ";server=" & server & ";"
            cn.Open()
            cmd.Connection = cn
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@poOrdNum", poOrdNum))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@poLineNum", poLineNum))
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = SQL
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Return True
        Catch
            Throw
        Finally
            If Not IsNothing(cmd) Then cmd.Dispose()
            If Not IsNothing(cn) Then cn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Function

    Private Function sendBadPOLineEmailtoDepot(ByVal msgText As String) As Boolean
        Try
            If ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("EnableSentBadPOMail").ToLower <> "true" Then Return True
            Dim sMailServer As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MailServer")
            Dim mySmtpClient As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(sMailServer)
            mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = True
            mySmtpClient.DeliveryMethod = Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
            Dim sTo As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("BadPOMailTo")
            Dim sFrom As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("BadPOMailFrom")


            mySmtpClient.Send(sFrom, sTo, msgText, msgText)

            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Exception sending sending bad PO line e-mail to depot: " & ex.Message)
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

End Class
```

Update: I don't want the output to be overwritten, I want it appended. Thus the >> and not >

Update:
The outlooks the same in the console window, ie. if not redirected to a file. This is the application outputing to this file and only one runs at a time. There doesn't appear  to be any bad data in the clients database.

I am confident that the code between site is the same. Also, I have made sure there are no extra console.write/writeline creating the problem.

Update: I was missing some code that could be relevent, I have updated the code snippet above.

Update: I have been running the process "by hand" at my client so I'm sure only one was running. The  ProcessPartDepotOrders() is simply called once from sub main(), so I can't see there being any threading issues.

Comment: Are these run from the same thread? Can you post some relevant code?

Comment: What does the output look like if you don't redirect to a file?  In other words, can you rule out the redirect as a cause of the problem?

Comment: Is another application writing to the same log file at the same time?

Comment: Could the database itself on the customers site contain bad character data?

Comment: Where do you output the date? Couldn't see where it's coming from. DB?

Comment: Could it be that there is a line with Console.Write instead of Console.Writeline writing the date somewhere?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the code you're running at the customer's site is the same code you're running at your test site?

Comment: no Console.Write, first thing I looked for. Code is the same between sites.

Comment: But where do you output the date?

Comment: I'm guessing in the CreateLine() function

Comment: Nevermind: date is output outside of this snippet

Comment: I updated my answer, so I'm posting to make sure you see it.

Answer (score 1):

Good job using the newer `If` rather than `IIf`.  However, there are some other constructs in your code that are still throwbacks from vb6.  The biggest is that the new AndAlso operator allows use of a real control/break style loop structure.  There's also no need to set to Nothing after disposing an object in .Net, you can use the `Using` keyword to better handle disposing and finally blocks, and the .Net style guidelines specifically recommend against the use of hungarian notation warts like 's' or 'cls'.

I took the liberty of restructuring your code to take advantage of that, so we'll start here.  Before I move further I want to make sure this refactor hasn't introduced new bugs:

#### Update:

Updated my post to show all your refactored code.  Note some simple name changes, as well as factoring out the connection string and changing how the OpenWiSysConn() function works.

```
Public Class PartsDepot
    Public Function ProcessPartDepotOrders() As Boolean
        Dim errMsg As String = ""
        Try
            Console.WriteLine(Now)
            ''//sendBadPOLineEmailtoDepot("test")
            Dim POData As New DataSet
            Dim dbName As String = ""
            Dim dbServer As String
            Dim partDepotDbName As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("partDepotDbName")
            Dim partDepotDbServer As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("partdepotDBserver")
            Dim KeyName As String = ""
            Dim billToCompany As String ''//, billtoCompAddr1 As String
            Dim dtBillTo As DataTable


            Dim i As Integer = 1
            Dim appkeyQry = From key In ConfigurationManager.AppSettings Where key Like "CompanyDbName*" Select key

            ''//for each company database look for PO's
            For Each KeyName In appkeyQry
                dbName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(KeyName)
                dbServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CompanyDbServer" & i)
                billToCompany = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(dbName)

                dtBillTo = GetCustomer(billToCompany, partDepotDbName, partDepotDbServer)
                If dtBillTo.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                    Throw New Exception("Customer record for company database '" & dbName & "' not found in the parts depot!")
                End If
                ''//billtoCompAddr1 = dtBillTo.Rows(0)("cmp_fadd1")

                ''//get all the unprocessed, printed PO's from the current company.
                POData  = GetPoDataset(dbName, dbServer)

                If POData Is Nothing Then
                    ''// do you really want to quit here, or do you want to move to the next key? 
                    ''// Your error handling is.. inconsistent
                    Console.WriteLine("Error processing part depot: " & errMsg)
                    Exit Function
                End If

                Dim itemNum As String, qtyOrd As Double, requestDate As Date, promiseDate As Date, lineNum As String, itemPrice As Double
                Dim errNum As Integer = 0
                Dim poNum As String

                ''//use control/break style processing loop
                Dim dt As DataTable = POData.Tables(0) ''// save some typing later
                Dim dr As DataRow = dt.Rows(0)
                Dim j As Integer = 0 ''// 'i' is already in use
                While j < dt.Rows.Count   ''//for each unprocessed, printed PO in the current company

                    ''//Do setup work for next Order Number
                    Console.WriteLine("Processing PO#: " & dr("ord_no") & " in " & dbName)

                    Using wsConn As Wisys.Allsystem.ConnectionInfo = OpenWiSysConn(partDepotDbName, partDepotDbServer, True), _
                          wsPartDepotSalesOrd As New Wisys.Oe.OrderEntryTables

                        wsPartDepotSalesOrd.Connection(wsConn, errMsg)

                        With wsPartDepotSalesOrd.OrderHeader
                            .UserName = My.User.Name
                            .Ship_to_name = If(IsDBNull(dr("cmp_name")), "", dr("cmp_name"))
                            .Ship_to_addr_1 = If(IsDBNull(dr("cmp_fadd1")), "", dr("cmp_fadd1"))
                            .Ship_to_addr_2 = If(IsDBNull(dr("cmp_fadd2")), "", dr("cmp_fadd2"))
                            .Ship_to_addr_3 = If(IsDBNull(dr("cmp_fadd3")), "", dr("cmp_fadd3"))
                            .Ship_to_addr_4 = If(IsDBNull(dr("cmp_fcity")), "", dr("cmp_fcity")) & " , " & _
                                If(IsDBNull(dr("StateCode")), "", dr("StateCode"))
                            .Ship_to_country = If(IsDBNull(dr("cmp_fcounty")), "", dr("cmp_fcounty"))
                            .Oe_po_no = dr("ord_no")
                        End With

                        ''//wsPartDepotSalesOrd.OrderHeader.Status 'readonly
                        errNum = wsPartDepotSalesOrd.OrderHeader.Insert(TrxEnums.OeOrderTypeEnum.Order, "", billToCompany, "", dr("ord_dt"), errMsg)
                        If errNum <> 0 Then
                            Console.WriteLine("Error Creating OE header:" & errMsg)
                        Else
                            Console.WriteLine("Created OE#" & wsPartDepotSalesOrd.OrderHeader.Ord_no)
                        End If

                        poNum = dr("ord_no")

                        ''//Process individual lines within one order
                        While j < dt.Rows.Count AndAlso poNum = dr("ord_no")
                            ''//if error then skip to the next loop iteration until the next PO # and it gets inserted ok
                            If errNum <> 0 Then
                                lineNum = If(IsDBNull(dr("line_no")), Now(), dr("line_no"))
                                itemNum = dr("item_no").ToString
                                qtyOrd = If(IsDBNull(dr("qty_ordered")), 0, CDbl(dr("qty_ordered")))
                                requestDate = If(IsDBNull(dr("request_dt")), Now(), dr("request_dt"))
                                promiseDate = If(IsDBNull(dr("promise_dt")), Now(), dr("promise_dt"))
                                itemPrice = If(IsDBNull(dr("price")), 0, dr("price"))

                                If itemNum.Length > 0 AndAlso qtyOrd <> 0 Then
                                    CreateLine(wsPartDepotSalesOrd, itemNum, qtyOrd, 0, requestDate, requestDate, promiseDate, itemPrice)
                                    ''//mark as processed, even if above fails. any lines that fail will be added to SO in parts depot by hand.
                                    markPoLineAsProcessed(dbName, dbServer, poNum, lineNum)
                                End If
                            End If
                            j += 1
                            dr = dt.Rows(j)
                        End While
                        ''//Do cleanup work from this order
                        wsConn.CloseWisysConnection(TrxEnums.TransactionAction.Commit, errMsg)
                    End Using ''// "End Using" will dispose of wsConn and wsPartDepotSalesOrd 
                End While

                poNum = ""
                i += 1
            Next KeyName
            Console.WriteLine("DONE")

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Exception processing part depot: " & ex.Message)
        End Try ''// No need for finally section: Using statement ensures the objects were disposed
    End Function

    Private Function GetCustomer(ByVal CustomerNum As String, ByVal db As String, ByVal server As String) As DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Using cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(GetConnectionString(db, server)), _
                cmd As New SqlCommand("select cmp_name,cmp_fadd1,coalesce(debnr,crdnr) as CusNum from dbo.cicmpy where ltrim(debnr) = @cusnum or ltrim(crdnr) = @cusnum", cn), _
                da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@cusnum", CustomerNum))
            da.Fill(ds) ''// .Fill() will open the connection if needed
        End Using ''// Using statement guarantees cn, cmd, and da are disposed
        If ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            Return ds.Tables(0)
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Private Function GetPoDataset(ByVal db As String, ByVal server As String) As DataSet
        Static Dim SQL As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("getPoforPartsDepotSQL")

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Using cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(GetConnectionString(db, server)), _
                cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, cn), _
                da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

            da.Fill(ds)
        End Using
        Return ds
    End Function

    Private Function GetConnectionString(ByVal db As String, ByVal server As String)
        Return String.Format("Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog={0};server={1}", db, server)
    End Function

    Private Function OpenWiSysConn(ByVal dbName As String, ByVal dbServer As String, ByVal useTran As Boolean) As Wisys.Allsystem.ConnectionInfo
        Dim ci As New Wisys.Allsystem.ConnectionInfo()
        ci.Parameters(dbServer, dbName, "MacMSS")

        Dim errMsg As String = String.Empty
        If ci.OpenWisysConnection(useTran, errMsg) <> 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Error processing part depot: " & errMsg)
            Return Nothing
        End If
        Return ci
    End Function

    Private Function CreateLine(ByVal OEObj As Wisys.Oe.OrderEntryTables, ByVal partNum As String, ByVal qtyOrdered As Double, ByVal qtyToShip As Double, ByVal RequestDate As Date, ByVal RequestShipDate As Date, ByVal PromiseDate As Date, ByVal price As Double, ByVal PONum As String) As Boolean
        Dim OeLine As OEORDLIN
        Dim RtnErrMsg As String = ""
        Dim RtnVal As Long
        Dim RtnLineNumber As Long

        With OEObj
            ''//p_lRtnVal = .OrderHeader.Read(TrxEnums.OeOrderTypeEnum.Order, RtnOrder, True, True, True, RtnRecFound, RtnErrMsg)
            OeLine = .OrderHeader.OrderLines.Add(TrxEnums.OrderLineType.InventoryItem, partNum.ToUpper, "", qtyOrdered, qtyToShip, price, price, RequestDate, PromiseDate, RequestShipDate, True, RtnErrMsg)
            RtnVal = OeLine.Insert(RtnLineNumber, RtnErrMsg)

            If RtnVal = 0 Then Return True

            Console.WriteLine("Error creating sales order line# " & RtnLineNumber & ": " & RtnErrMsg)
            sendBadPOLineEmailtoDepot("Error creating sales order line for PO# " & PONum & " because of an error: " & RtnErrMsg)
            Return False
        End With
    End Function

    Private Function markPoLineAsProcessed(ByVal DB As String, ByVal server As String, ByVal poOrdNum As String, ByVal poLineNum As String) As Boolean
        Static Dim SQL As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("markPoLineAsSendToDepotSQL")

        Using cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(GetConnectionString(DB, server)), _
             cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(SQL, cn)

            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@poOrdNum", poOrdNum))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@poLineNum", poLineNum))

            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
        Return True
    End Function

    Private Function sendBadPOLineEmailtoDepot(ByVal msgText As String) As Boolean
        Try
            If ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("EnableSentBadPOMail").ToLower <> "true" Then Return True
            Dim MailServer As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MailServer")
            Dim ToAddress As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("BadPOMailTo")
            Dim FromAddress As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("BadPOMailFrom")

            Dim mySmtpClient As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(MailServer)
            mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = True
            mySmtpClient.DeliveryMethod = Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network

            mySmtpClient.Send(FromAddress, ToAddress, msgText, msgText)
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Exception sending sending bad PO line e-mail to depot: " & ex.Message)
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

As to your specific error:  it looks like you are sometimes writing through a buffer and sometimes bypassing the buffer.  Alternatively, if each of the 'record' segments in the file (where a record begins with the date and ends with 'DONE') is the result of a separate instance of your app, you might also be seeing the result of several instances writing to the file at the same time.  This also makes sense because the amount of traffic is one big potential difference between the server and your test environment.

Comment: Thanks. I do use AndAlso when I feel it's warranted. I also do a lot of VB6 coding 8P - bad habbits die hard

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that  this is running on one thread?  It almost looks like several iterations are running at once and writing to the same pipe (stdout/console.wl).
Try writing your logs to a file, having a different log for each iteration in appkeyqry (like 'log-{date}.txt').
Perhaps your server is multicore and you have a race condition?

Edit:
Try flushing stdout after each Console.Write (Console.Out.Flush)
It may be the reason your output is out of order.
(I write a lot of perl scripts, and on a fast server unless you set stdout to always flush after each write, the output gets all mixed up just like yours).

HTH, really ;)